Custom event in Sentry to adding username and email to track the issue
how I can do Custom event in Sentry to adding username and email to track the issue in my code flutter I have the package and is running but I don't know how add username and email to track
I try this code Sentry.configureScope((scope) {
scope.setUser(SentryUser(
id: 'unique-user-id',
username: 'your-username',
email: 'user@example.com',

I believe this is what you need -> https://docs.sentry.io/platforms/flutter/enriching-events/identify-user/
Basically you can configure the scope like this
Sentry.configureScope(
  (scope) => scope.setUser(SentryUser(id: '1234', email: 'jane.doe@example.com')),
);

If this is not working for you maybe a try/catch block can help you, or even log something to the console.
